# How to use js variable in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use JavaScript variables in jQuery selectors?

```
(function($){

var words = $('#readpcd').text().match(/(\w+)/g);
if (words.length) {
    var lastword = words[words.length - 1];
}
console.log(lastword);
 
$('select option[value=" + this.lastword +"]').attr("selected","selected");


}(jQuery || window.jQuery));
```

i tried

```
$('select option[value="${lastword}"]').attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: You need to use backticks (`\``) not single quotes for template literals

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1. String Concatenation

   ```
   $('select option[value="'+lastword+'"]')
   ```
2. Variable injection

   ```
   $(`select option[value="${lastword}"]`)
   ```

(You need to use ` instead of ')

Answer (score 0):

Use template literals (using backticks ``` `` ```)

```
 $(`select option[value="${lastword}"]`).attr("selected","selected");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
$('select option[value=' + lastword + ']').attr("selected","selected");
```

Answer (score -2):

change this line

```
$('select option[value=" + this.lastword +"]').attr("selected","selected");
```

to this

```
$('select option[value="' + lastword + '"]').attr("selected","selected");
```

lastword is a local variable. you cannot use it as this.lastword.

and if you want to use it inline the use backticks

```
$(`select option[value="${lastword}"]`).attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: thanks but this still does not change the select options if i use $('select option[value="text"]').attr("selected","selected");  it work

Comment: i updated my answer if you want to using it with backticks @MattSmith

Comment: I believe the second line of code is still incorrect, you are missing quotations to break the String.

Comment: thanks @Danbardo, i corrected it